# Error message rendering multiple times - each time submit button is pressed with empty input field & the error messages remain even after input

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am finishing up my coding for a quiz app where questions are rendered one at a time and then finally the results table is rendered.  Users can submit score and name to a scoreboard on another page.  When the name input field is empty and the submit button is pressed, an error message is triggered.  It was working fine if I did an alert

```
`else {
    alert("Please input your your name before submitting your score");
  }`
```

However, I don't want an alert.  I want something a bit nicer so I did the following code.  But every time button is submitted, the error is seen and then there ends up being multiple messages AND it doesn't go away even after the input field is populated. IDEALLY, I would like the error to render under the input field and not the submit button but I am fine, if this is not possible. Everything else works fine.

`fname` is the input field

`renderHighScores` has been declared elsewhere.

```
const handleResultsForm = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  //get name from form
  const fullName = document.getElementById("fname").value;

  if (fullName) {
    const yourScore = {
      userName: fullName,
      score: timerValue,
    };

    const highScores = readFromLocalStorage();

    //push score object into LS
    highScores.push(yourScore);

    highScores.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);

    writeToLocalStorage("highscores", highScores);

    // render high scores page
    renderHighScores();
  } else {
    //if name input is empty show error message
    const nameInput = document.createElement("p");
    nameInput.setAttribute("class", "confirm-name");
    nameInput.setAttribute("id", "error-name");
    nameInput.textContent = "Please enter your name";

    const fullName = document.getElementById("submit-to-high-scores-button");
    fullName.appendChild(nameInput);
  }
};


  // add submit event handler to form
  submitScoresBtn.addEventListener("click", handleResultsForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating the error message element upon page load, but hidden. Then when you want to show it, just change its `display` style. And as soon as the user starts typing, hide it again.

```
// Create the error element at page load
const nameInput = document.createElement("p");
nameInput.setAttribute("class", "confirm-name");
nameInput.setAttribute("id", "error-name");
nameInput.textContent = "Please enter your name";
nameInput.style.display = "none"; // But hide it
const fullName = document.getElementById("submit-to-high-scores-button");
fullName.appendChild(nameInput);

const handleResultsForm = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  //get name from form
  const fullName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  // Set the visibility of the error message
  nameInput.style.display = fullName ? "none" : "";

  if (fullName) {
    const yourScore = {
      userName: fullName,
      score: timerValue,
    };

    const highScores = readFromLocalStorage();

    //push score object into LS
    highScores.push(yourScore);

    highScores.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);

    writeToLocalStorage("highscores", highScores);

    // render high scores page
    renderHighScores();
  }
};

// add submit event handler to form
submitScoresBtn.addEventListener("click", handleResultsForm);

// Hide the error message when user edits the name.
document.getElementById("fname").addEventListener("input", () => {
    nameInput.style.display = "none";
});
```

Comment: Hi. I moved the create error element to the page load but now I'm receiving an error message ` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')`  - I think it's because the `#submit-to-high-scores-button` (for `docment.getElementById`) is created within the same function?

Comment: You have to make sure the script executes when the page is loaded, so make sure the script is at the bottom of the page, when the document is ready.

Comment: Forgot to say I just added `const nameInput = document.getElementById("error-name");` to the `handleResultsForm` just before the ternary operator to make it work.  In case anyone else comes across the post.

Comment: It is there as a global variable.

Comment: Mmmm. I tried that but it didn't work for me.  Console log  kept showing `nameInput` as `undefined` in `handleResultsForm` function.   I'm not enough experience to work out why.

Comment: There must be something different then at your end. Did you put the initial lines of code inside a function maybe?